# Send logs from a REST service to an HTML page

Tags: java, rest

I have a REST service on a server A. The service is doing some stuff and logging some messages thanks to log4j.

Aside, I have a web page on server B that is calling the service thanks to AJAX and getting the response. Apart from receiving the response (which works fine to me), I would like to print on the page the log messages from the server side.

In other words, I would like that every time there is a new log message on server A side, the view display it.

Any ideas to achieve that ?

**EDIT:**
How to use a websocket to retrieve logs from a log4j socket appender?

Comment: Storing logs in db sounds more easier for me

Comment: log4j is a dev-stuff, language level. Don't mix it with business requirements. Just implement another business-level stuff to send info via rest explicitly.

Comment: @kan has agood point

Comment: Should I then create another Rest service that can get the list of log from the server. And then call every, let say 5 seconds, this service to upload the logs in the view ?

Comment: Are you sure you want send logs outside? They are for developers/prod support only. It even could be a security info leak. If you want a REST service to send some info - send it explicitly. Do not give away arbitrary access to arbitrary data.

Comment: In fact, I want to inform the user of what is happening while the service is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to solve my problem:

I have created a singleton logger. Every time I want to log a message, I am getting the instance of the logger and add the new message to the ConcurrentLinkedList of logs.

On the other hand, I have created a new rest service. Every second I call this service with an ajax query. It removes the log messages of the list and return them. The view display them.

Answer (score 0):

You would create a REST endpoint to retrieve the raw log data as `text/plain`. It could be something as following:

```
GET /logs HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/plain
```

You also could provide some query string parameters to filter the logs by date and time, as following:

```
GET /logs?from=2016-07-03T10:00:00Z&to=2016-07-04T10:00:00Z HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/plain
```

Then your client can request such endpoint, retrieve the data they want to and display the logs in a HTML page.

If you prefer rendering the HTML page on server side, instead of accepting `text/plain`, accept `text/html`.

---

For real time logging, you could consider [WebSockets](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).

Comment: Then If I want real time retrieving for logs, I can execute every second an ajax request to the endpoint and update the div that display the log on the html page. Do you think it is a good solution?

Comment: @L01c For real time, you could consider websockets.